# Galaxy Note 4.0.4 upgrade failure

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, updates, samsung-kies, samsung-galaxy-note

My Samsung Galaxy Note (GT-N7000) currently has 4.0.3 installed. It has let me know it has the upgrade for 4.0.4 but every time I run it, it fails. After failure it will boot back up fine and has a message it has failed and I should try update with Kies (which doesn't work either).

I can't find anyone else with the same problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you located? Who is your carrier?

Comment: Nevermind. It eventually worked after about the 20th time. No reason why it worked, it just did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue solved itself over time with no changes needed.

Comment: @Flow give him 2 more days to do so :)

Comment: A right, sorry forgot about that limit.